# Add javascript variable to html error undefined

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I've been using this search script for several years and I recently encountered a problem where some users "Enter" key wasn't committing to the page so the return false; would then place the html address on the address line but it will not allow me to enter the value of my text box in with the html code.

As you can see I'm new to javascript and the code was created by Peter Allen from a SharePoint site.

I basically need when the Enter Key fails on the page to write the address line with the value of the variable...

Please help I'm begging SOMEONE!!!

```
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
// This displays the Solution Info when the user is in Edit Page mode.
$(document).ready(function(){
// Variables are commented out till needed.
var opt2aa213hd = $('#option2-aa213hd').text();
var opt3aa213hd = $('#option3-aa213hd').text();

 $('#FilterList').css('text-align', opt2aa213hd);
 $('#searchTitle').append(opt3aa213hd);

$('#Search').keyup(function(e) {
    //alert(e.keyCode);
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#searchClick').click();
    }
});
 });
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>

$(document).ready(function(){
var searchString = document.location.search;

// strip off the leading '?'
searchString = searchString.substring(1);

var nvPairs = searchString.split("&");
     var nvPair = nvPairs[0].split("=");
     var name = nvPair[0];
     var value = nvPair[1];
$("input#Search").val(value);
var green = $("input#Search").val(value);;
});

</SCRIPT>

<DIV style="TEXT-ALIGN: right; FONT-WEIGHT: bold" id=FilterList>
<TABLE>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD>
<DIV style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold" id=searchTitle></DIV></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD><INPUT id=Search name=Search> 
<A style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold" id=searchClick onclick="document.location.href = $('#option1-aa213hd').text()+'?Search='+$('#Search').val(); 
return false;" href="http://mywebsite.aspx?Search=**green**&amp;PageView=Shared#">Search</A> 
<DIV></DIV>
<DIV></DIV></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV>
```

Comment: Look into `addEventListener` to add the events in JavaScript, not in the markup.

Comment: Thank for your comment but were would I put that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `javascript:` pseudo before using javscript in html onclick attribute.

Replace this:

```
onclick="document.location.href = $('#option1-aa213hd').text()+'?Search='+$('#Search').val(); 
return false;"
```

With this:

```
onclick="javascript:document.location.href = $('#option1-aa213hd').text()+'?Search='+$('#Search').val(); 
return false;"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  When I add the " javascript:document" it disables my onclick.